# Pandas Iterate over rows and create a new column with the sum

Tags: python, pandas

I am newby to Pandas and maybe my question/problem is very easy.
I have a dataframe with shape n*3 and I want to create a new column (fourth) where I will add the values of the other columns (column1 + column2 + column3)

I tried this and although I print the sum with correct summary values I cannot save it to the new column.

```
for index, row  in answers.iterrows():
    mydf[index, 3] = mydf.iloc[index, 0] + mydf.iloc[index, 1] + mydf.iloc[index, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [DataFrame.sum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
mydf['sum'] = mydf.sum(axis=1)
```

If you want only few columns, make a column list and the sum over them:

```
col_list =['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
mydf['sum'] = mydf[col_list].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: I want to add only some columns not all! @Mohit Motwani

Comment: check the edited answer